# Using Case Statement to Compare and Exclude

Tags: case, teradata

(Working in Teradata) I've been tasked with comparing the values of any of 3 specific columns to 3 other specific columns. I would include the record if a value from one of the initial 3 specified columns match the value of any of the second set of 3 columns.

Columns 
Diag_Prefix, Diag2_Prefix, and Diag3_Prefix
are being compared to
Xref_Diag_Prefix, Xref_Dia2g_Prefix , Xref_Diag2_Prefix

So, as an example, if Diag_Prefix contains value A10 and that value is also contained in Xref_Diag_Prefix, OR Xref_Dia2g_Prefix, OR Xref_Diag2_Prefix then I would keep the record, otherwise I would exclude it.

I believe I have this part down as follows:

```
AND (CASE WHEN Diag_Prefix = Xref_Diag_Prefix OR Diag_Prefix = Xref_Diag2_Prefix OR Diag_Prefix = Xref_Diag3_Prefix
    OR Diag2_Prefix = Xref_Diag_Prefix OR Diag2_Prefix = Xref_Diag2_Prefix OR Diag2_Prefix = Xref_Diag3_Prefix
    OR Diag3_Prefix = Xref_Diag_Prefix OR Diag3_Prefix = Xref_Diag2_Prefix OR Diag3_Prefix = Xref_Diag3_Prefix
    THEN 'I' ELSE 'E' END) = 'I'
```

My problem is that some of the values in these columns are 'NULL' and have been populated with the value of 'UNK' in such cases. These records are being included with my CASE statement above, so I'm trying to change the UNK values into something unique for each field, as follows:

```
    /* Converting UNK values to exclude from subsequent comparison case statement */
    AND (CASE WHEN Diag_Prefix = 'UNK' THEN 'UNKD1' ELSE Diag_Prefix END)
    AND (CASE WHEN Diag2_Prefix = 'UNK' THEN 'UNKD2' ELSE Diag2_Prefix END)
    AND (CASE WHEN Diag3_Prefix = 'UNK' THEN 'UNKD3' ELSE Diag3_Prefix END)
    AND (CASE WHEN Xref_Diag_Prefix = 'UNK' THEN 'UNKX1' ELSE Xref_Diag_Prefix END)
    AND (CASE WHEN Xref_Diag2_Prefix = 'UNK' THEN 'UNKX2' ELSE Xref_Diag2_Prefix END)
    AND (CASE WHEN Xref_Diag3_Prefix = 'UNK' THEN 'UNKX3' ELSE Xref_Diag3_Prefix END)
```

But this is giving me an error that states: "...expected something like a 'SUCCEEDS', 'MEETS', 'PRECEDES', 'IN', or 'CONTAINS' keyword between ')' and the 'AND' keyword."

I'm not sure if it would be easier to just create a VT somehow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it would be easier to do without the CASE statement getting in the way and just ignoring the 'UNK' values entirely:

```
WHERE
    ((
        Diag_Prefix = Xref_Diag_Prefix
        OR Diag_Prefix = Xref_Diag2_Prefix
        OR Diag_Prefix = Xref_Diag3_Prefix
    ) AND Diag_Prefix <> 'UNK')
    OR ((
        Diag2_Prefix = Xref_Diag_Prefix
        OR Diag2_Prefix = Xref_Diag2_Prefix
        OR Diag2_Prefix = Xref_Diag3_Prefix
    ) AND Diag2_Prefix <> 'UNK')
    OR ((
        Diag3_Prefix = Xref_Diag_Prefix
        OR Diag3_Prefix = Xref_Diag2_Prefix
        OR Diag3_Prefix = Xref_Diag3_Prefix
    ) AND Diag3_Prefix <> 'UNK'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This won't work since it will exclude all records where either the Diag_Prefix, Diag2_Prefix, or Diag3_Prefix = 'UNK'. There are valid records where at least one of these fields has the value of 'UNK'.

Comment: For example, one of the records has G89, UNK, UNK as the values for the above columns. The xref columns those values are being compared to have G89, G89 and M17. Since G89 is found on both sets of columns, I would want to keep this record, but the code above would exclude it since Diag2_Prefix and Diag3_Prefix contain the value of 'UNK'.

Comment: @JoeX: No, it will *not* exclude it, because `G89 <> 'UNK'` and the other conditions are ORed, not ANDed.

Comment: @dnoeth, my mistake, you're absolutely right. JNevill, thanks for the reply, code worked perfectly.